# Cómo aplicar un anchor a un desplegable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Con la siguiente función consigo que se habrán los diferentes desplegables de una página, sin embargo, cada vez que se abre uno, la página vuelve arriba. He leído que aplicando un anchor se soluciona pero no sé como hacerlo. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

Función:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<8; i++){
        $("#desplegable"+i).css({display:'none'});
    }
});
function desplegable(d){
    $("#desplegable"+d).slideToggle("slow");
}
```

Desplegables:

```
 <div name="LUNES">
     <div class="row" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(117, 178, 212, 0.41);height: 51px; ">
          <p  class="col-md-11 col-lg-11" style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 20px"><strong>LUNES</strong></p>
            <a href="#" id="dias1" onclick="desplegable(1)" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 5px">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
           </a>
       </div>
   </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div id="desplegable1"></div>

     </div>
 </div>
```

```
<div name="MARTES">
  <div class="row" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px">
     <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(117, 178, 212, 0.41);height: 51px; ">
      <p  class="col-md-11 col-lg-11" style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 20px"><strong>MARTES</strong></p>
       <a href="#" id="dias2" onclick="desplegable(2)" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 5px">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div id="desplegable2">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que, al hacer click en el link, a parte de ejecutarse la función `desplegable` el navegador ejecuta el comportamiento por defecto del link: navegar a la url del href. En tu caso el href de los links es `"#"` lo que equivale a "ir al comienzo de la página". Para anular este comportamiento por defecto puedes ejecutar el método `preventDefault` del objeto Event en el controlador del evento click, o simplemente que el `onclick` devuelva un `return false`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var texto = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis turpis justo. Etiam ac convallis ipsum, facilisis tincidunt elit. Nulla purus nunc, varius et consectetur id, fermentum vel tortor. Phasellus id quam arcu. Quisque ornare pharetra quam, in volutpat nulla cursus non. Quisque arcu purus, rhoncus eget magna id, pulvinar tempor lacus. Curabitur tempor, magna ullamcorper sagittis porttitor, turpis diam rutrum mauris, eget faucibus quam urna sollicitudin magna. Curabitur suscipit felis tortor, in aliquet mauris sodales quis.';
    for(var i=0;i<8; i++){
        $("#desplegable"+i).css({display:'none'});
        $("#desplegable"+i).text(texto);
    }
});
function desplegable(d){
    $("#desplegable"+d).slideToggle("slow");
    return false;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div name="LUNES">
     <div class="row" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(117, 178, 212, 0.41);height: 51px; ">
          <p  class="col-md-11 col-lg-11" style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 20px"><strong>LUNES</strong></p>
            <a href="#" id="dias1" onclick="return desplegable(1)" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 5px">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
           </a>
       </div>
   </div>
       <div class="row">
           <div id="desplegable1"></div>

     </div>
 </div>
<div name="MARTES">
  <div class="row" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px">
     <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(117, 178, 212, 0.41);height: 51px; ">
      <p  class="col-md-11 col-lg-11" style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 20px"><strong>MARTES</strong></p>
       <a href="#" id="dias2" onclick="return desplegable(2)" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 5px">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div id="desplegable2">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Funciona :)